# find area of square part

Tags: geometry, circles

let us consider following  picture

[image]

where $ABCD$ is square, and using $A$ and  $C$ as center,there is drawn  arc,we should find  area of dark part.we know that length of square is $a$,as i see the  parts of intersection   or $ABK$ and  $CBK$ are congruent or  equal to each other,so  in my opinion area of  dark part is equal

$a^2-((a^2-\pi*a^2/4)/2+a^2-\pi*a^2/4)$

because    $ACD$ represent  as  quarter of circle  with radius $a$ and it's area is $\pi*a^2/4$,by substraction i will find are of  $ABC$ and  by dividng  by $2$,i will find  $BKC$,then  idea is substract area of  $ABD+BKC$  from $a^2$,is it correct?please help me,answer is $(\sqrt{3}/4-\pi/12)*a^2$  where  $\sqrt{3}$ comes from?thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The triangle $\Delta AKD$ is equilateral. Thus, the area of the shape $AKD$ (with arcs $AK$ and $KD$ as edges) is equal to twice the area of $60^\circ$ sectors of a circle with radius $a$ minus the area of the triangle $AKD$. So area of the shape $AKD$ can be written as $2\pi a^2/6-a^2\sqrt{3}/4$. Subtracting this area from the area of the quarter circle $ACD$ gives us the answer $$\pi a^2/4-(\pi a^2/3-a^2\sqrt{3}/4)=a^2(\sqrt{3}/4-\pi/12), $$ as desired.

Comment: sorry could you explain a little more detailed?why it is $AKD$ equilateral?

Comment: also what about  $AK$ and  $KD$ arc?

Comment: i can't sector of  $60$,could you draw it seperately?

Comment: $AK$ is radius of the quarter circle $ABD$, so it is equal to $AD=a$. Similarly $KD=a$. So $AK=KD=AD =a$ and $AKD$ is equilateral. Now the area enclosed by the arcs $AK$, $DK$, and the side $AD$ is the area of the two $60^\circ$ sectors $DKA$ (centered at $D$) and $AKD$ (centered at $A$) minus the area of $equilateral triangle $AKD$. Basically, we count the area of the triangle twice when we add the area of the two sectors so we have to subtract it.

Comment: but   segments  $Ak$ and $KD$ are equal right?

Comment: Yes. What's the problem with that?

Comment: now i was thinking that   we can divide  it into three  part.because  it is square,we could substract  from quarter circle  area of  sector equilater triangle and sector with $30$ degree,$90-60$,but it seems a  problem

Comment: also  angle $60$ belongs on triangle,not segment

Comment: so my idea is   quarter of circle minus  sector with  $30$ degree and minus are of triangle,i will get area of segment $kd$,is this right?

Comment: If you mean the area enclosed by line segment $KD$ and arc $KD$ then yes. The key observation was to see the equilateral triangle. Then you can compute the shaded area in different but similar ways. All of them end up giving you the same result.