# In a square ABCD with side 14cm, 2 quadrants were made with centres A & B respectively and AB as radius. Find area of region I and II

Tags: algebraic-geometry, area

https://photos.app.goo.gl/5ibXDN5u6s0yo6KB3

I could do the following:

II + III = $\frac{1}{4}$ × $π$ × $14^2$ = $49π$ = $154cm^2$

II + IV = $\frac{1}{4}$ × $π$ × $14^2$ = $49π = 154 cm^2$

Area of square = $I + II + III + IV$ = $14^2 = 196 cm^2$

$(I + II + III +।V ) - ((II + III) + (II + IV)) = 196 - (154 + 154) = -112$

$\mapsto$ I - II = -112

$\mapsto$ II - I = 112

Am I going on the correct path?

Comment: could you perhaps add a figure, I'm not able to understand completely

Comment: It is possible, I have the answer. Writing it out now.

Comment: Only DAB and CBA are quadrants. No, the question is accurate because it is from my exam and some students were even able to answer it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using help from the answer of Landuros, I figured out the answer.

$II + III$ = $\frac{1}{4}$ × $π$ × $14^2$ = $49π$ = $154cm^2$

$II + IV$ = $\frac{1}{4}$ × $π$ × $14^2$ = $49π = 154 cm^2$

Area of square = $I + II + III + IV$ = $14^2 = 196 cm^2$

$(I + II + III +।V ) - ((II + III) + (II + IV)) = 196 - (154 + 154) = -112$

$\mapsto$ I - II = -112

$\mapsto$ II - I = 112

As seen from Landuros' answer, triangle EAB is equilateral.
Therefore, $\angle$ EBA = 60°.

Area of sector EBA = $\frac{60}{360} \times \pi 14^2$
                                   = $102.6 cm^2$

Area of $\triangle EAB$ = $ \frac{\sqrt 3}{4} \times 14^2$
                                           = $84.9 cm^2$

Area of each segment = $102.6 - 84.9$
                                        = $17.7$

Area of $II$ = $84.9 + 17.7 + 17.7$ 
                      = $120.3 cm^2$

We know that, $II - I = 112$
                          $\mapsto I = 8.3 cm^2$

Comment: Good answer. +1 upvote. This is essentially circular measure, except with more formal formulae and units.

Comment: Thanks Landuros

Answer (score 0):

HINT: The segment $II$ contains an equilateral triangle. The rest I think you can figure out.

I think you can use the relation given in [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/444184/find-area-of-square-part?rq=1) question to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Start by constructing $\overline {AE}$ and $\overline {EB}$. $E$ is the intersection of the arcs created by $ABD$ and $BAC$.

Notice that $\overline{AE} = \overline{EB} = \overline{AB} = 14$ because they are all radii of the circle. The points $A$, $B$ and $E$ form an equilateral triangle $\triangle ABE$. Hence, we know $\angle EAB = \angle ABE = \angle BEA = \frac{\pi}{3}$rad. You will need to be confident with radians rather than degrees, as we are working with circular measure.

\begin{align}
A_{\text{segment}} & = \frac{1}{2}r^2(\theta-\sin \theta) \\
\text{Segment} ~ EB & = \frac {1}{2} \cdot 14^2 ( \frac{\pi}{3}-\sin {\frac{\pi}{3}})\\
& = 98\cdot(\frac{\pi}{3}-\frac{\sqrt3}{2})
\end{align}

Segment $EB$ is congruent to segment $AE$, so both are $98\cdot(\frac{\pi}{3}-\frac{\sqrt3}{2})$ cm$^2$.

The area of II can be found by the following formula:

\begin{align}
\text{II} & = \text{Quadrant $ABC$} - \text{Sector $EBC$} + \text{Segment $EB$} \\
& = \frac{1}{4}\pi r^2 - \frac{1}{2}r^2 \theta + \text{Segment $EB$}\\
& = \frac{1}{4} \pi \cdot 14^2 - \frac{1}{2} \cdot 14^2 \cdot \frac{\pi}{6} + 98\cdot(\frac{\pi}{3}-\frac{\sqrt3}{2}) \\
& = 49\pi - \frac{49}{3}\pi + 98\cdot(\frac{\pi}{3}-\frac{\sqrt3}{2}) \\
& = 98(\frac{\pi}{3}-\frac{\sqrt3}{2})+\frac{98}{3}\pi \\
& = 98(\frac{2}{3}\pi-\frac{\sqrt3}{2}) \\
& \approx 120.380
\end{align}

As you see, it's not a very nice answer, but it is an exact answer for the area of II.

As for the area of I:

\begin{align}
\text{I} & = ABCD - \text{Quadrant $ABD$} - \text{Quadrant $CBA$} + \text{II} \\
& = 14^2 - 49\pi - 49\pi + 98(\frac{\pi}{3}-\frac{\sqrt3}{2})+\frac{98}{3}\pi \\
& = 98(\frac{\pi}{3}-\frac{\sqrt3}{2})-\frac{196}{3}\pi + 196\\
& \approx 8.504
\end{align}

So to summarise, $\text{I} = 8.504 ~\text{cm}^2$ and $\text{II} = 120.380 ~\text{cm}^2$ which sound about right.

Comment: As I am a student, concepts like 'radians' and the formula you used to find area of segment are out of my knowledge. But, there must some other answer also as this question was asked in my exam. Anyway, thanks for this answer.

Comment: @Aditya Pratap Singh Radians is simply a unit of measurement of angle, so, $360^\circ$= $2\pi$ now use the unitary method to figure out what $60^\circ$ is equal to.

Comment: $60° = \frac{\pi}{3}$

Comment: So radians means measuring angles in terms of $\pi$ ?

Comment: @AdityaPratapSingh Exactly. The unit of degrees is man-made; for example there is no specific reason why $360 °$ is a full revolution. Hence why we must use radians for calculus and circular measure.

Comment: @Aditya Pratap Singh In fact, there is another unit of measurement of angles if you care to find out.

Comment: @Prakhar Nagpal What is that unit? Guessing by your name, you are an Indian, I would like to give you my educational background. I am 14 year old and currently in Class 10. It would be great if you could please explain in such a manner which I am able to understand.

Comment: @Aditya Pratap Singh The third unit of angular measurement is called 'Gradians' or 'Grades' so $200$ Grades = $360^\circ$ = $2\pi$. And then you can figure out the rest using the unitary method.

Comment: @Prakhar Nagpal $100$ Grades $ = 180° = π $, right? By the way, where is Gradians used?

Comment: @Aditya Pratap Singh I don't think it is used anymore and yes $100$ Grades = $180^\circ$ = $\pi$

Comment: @Prakhar Nagpal Thanks for the knowledge