# Find $x$, if $2(a-b) + x(b-c)^2 + (c-a) ^3 = 2(a-d) + (b-d) ^2 +(c-d) ^3$, where $a, b, c, d$ are in AP series

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic-progressions

If $$2(a-b) + x(b-c)^2 + (c-a) ^3 = 2(a-d) + (b-d) ^2 +(c-d) ^3$$ where $a, b, c, d$ are four distinct real numbers and they are in Arithmetic Progression, then the possible value of $x$ can be:

(A) $-9$

(B) $-7$

(C) $14$

(D) $17$

**Edit:** Using help from the answer given by @NL628 I could figure this out.

> Let $a-b=k$ ,

Then, 
$\mapsto 2k + x \cdot k^2 + (-2k)^3 = 2 \cdot (3k) + (2k)^2 + k^3$

> Solving the quadratic equation for $k$ :

$$k = \frac{x-4 \pm \sqrt{x^2-8x-128}}{18}$$

What can I do now to find the value of $x$ ? What am I missing here?

Comment: Where are you confused exactly?

Comment: How to use the fact that $a, b, c, d$ are in A. P.

Comment: Yes, what methods have you tried? This SE is for people with problems figuring out certain questions. You have to say what you have tried and how you are stuck. Please put these things in the question.

Comment: You asked 6 (six) questions during the last 24 hours. This is quite a few. **None of them has any personal input**. Please stop the stream.

Comment: In first question I had provided a major lead in the question itself

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2586363/in-a-square-abcd-with-side-14cm-2-quadrants-were-made-with-centres-a-b-respec/2586441#

Comment: In other questions, I could provide nothing as I am a 14-year old student. I could make nothing out of those questions. These questions are from an olympiad that I had given few days back. Most of the concepts used in the questions like Law of Sines, Radians, etc. are completely unknown to me.

Comment: You can notice that in the first question, the answer given by Landuros was incomprehensible to me. Later I figured out another answer that used concepts known to me taking help from Landuros' answer.

Comment: @Did , now do you understand the reason why I could not give any **personal input**?

Comment: I can read the "reasons" you give, that are not good reasons. If all you can ask are questions with zero personal input, these are not suited to the site.

Comment: It is not that  I give zero personal input. @Did, I do my best to contribute as a student. And the page description of Mathematics Stack Exchange says that it is a Q&A for people studying maths **at any level**

Comment: If you have time @Did , please help me in the question

Comment: Any level, yes, of course, we all know this, **and this is not the problem**. At present you are misusing the site.

Comment: How am I supposedly misusing it? And how am I supposed to use it in a better manner?

Comment: 1. By posting questions with context. 2. By using @ in your comments. 3. By avoiding rhetorical questions in comments.

Comment: Ok @Did , I will try my best to adhere to your instructions. Is the first question correctly posted? As of now, please assist me with the above-mentioned question

Comment: "Is the first question correctly posted?" Of course not, where do you see some context? Since you deliberately transgressed my points 1. and 3., there is little use to continue this.

Comment: I have no other option to contact you @Did but through comments as chat is not available in my reputation. And please could you tell me what you mean by context. As I am from India and English isn't my first language, I am unable to understand what you are trying to say by the words context and rhetorical

Comment: Why dont you begin with the example sets $(1,2,3,4), (1,3,7,11)$ etc and guess what the $x$ can be in each case?

Answer (score 2):

Let $a - b = k.$ Thus, $b - c = k$ and $c - d = k$ because a, b, c, d are in arithmetic progression. Similarly, you can find out values for $a - d$ and $b - d.$

We see that the following equation simplifies to $$2k + x \cdot k^2 + (-2k)^3 = 2 \cdot (3k) + (2k)^2 + k^3$$.

With the single variable equation, I'll leave it to you to figure out the rest :)

Does this answer your question?

Comment: Won't this give $x$in terms of $k$?

Comment: Try finding $k$ in terms of $x$

Comment: I did $$ x = \frac{9k^2 + 4k +4}{k}$$

Comment: But the options are only in constants

Comment: Note how I said k in terms of x, not x in terms of k

Comment: $$k= \frac{x-4 \pm \sqrt{x^2-8x-128}}{18}$$